# What did seat belts look like in 1940s aircraft?

Tags: aviation-history, seatbelts

I first flew back in the 1940s as a four or five year old. I have a vague memory of a seat belt locked with a wooden peg inserted into a webbing loop. The aircraft was probably a Vickers Viking, a very unreliable aircraft.

We landed at Lyon, France, no wheels on the grass and we have a photograph of the crew and passengers in front of the downed aircraft in a field! Was there ever such a seat belt?

[image: aircraft in a field]

[image: aircraft in a field with crew & passengers in front of it]

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Can you add that picture of the aircraft to the question?

Comment: Related: [When did airlines start using seat belts for passengers?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39537/14897)

Comment: In the 40s you would mostly have seen those lever clamp type buckles that were popular up to the 60s, at least in North America. They were replaced with the modern ones because they were almost impossible to release if you were hanging upside down in the belt.  What you recall was most likely a belt that was just a big leather strap with holes and a buckle, like an oversized pants belt, that was common on British a/c up through WW2.

Comment: Firstly yes I have a shot of the Aircraft on the ground in what looks like a field but is just off the Lyon airfield runway. It is a Vickers Viking operated by Airwork and the occasion was around 1948/9. I have not found a way to upload the picture. I cannot see the registration of the aircraft. Square windows! They don't do that anymore after The Comet. Happy to upload the picture if there is a way.

Comment: My sister has produced a date for the accident - May17th 1948 and the the flight was ex Khartoum to UK but no airport!

Comment: Extraordinary story! Btw, there is a [book about Airwork](https://books.google.com/books?id=_607AwAAQBAJ), you may already know. I found a trace of a [BEA report](https://francearchives.fr/fr/facomponent/2cd3640b195a25553e3c89d0eabc7d9fa8ba29e1) "*aérodrome de Lyon-Bron (Rhône), Vicking (G-AIXS) 17 mai 1948*", but it isn't available online, likely not digitalized. This was an Airwork aircraft and was [lost 6 years later](https://www.baaa-acro.com/crash/crash-vickers-627-viking-1b-blackbushe) in an emergency return to Blackbushe. If I find something else I'll post it here.

Comment: Simply [edit] your question and drag the picture from your computer into the text edit box. The site will upload & host it for you.

Comment: @hutchinson is the problem with the picture that it's a paper photograph or a slide and you don't have a scanner to get the picture onto the computer?

Comment: I added in the pic with pax & crew from the deleted non-answer. Now, you just need to identify yourself! I'm guessing you're the young man standing closest to the squatting crewman.

Answer (score 4):

Your seatbelt, as a five year old, may have been an earlier version of the loops they still use for very young children when travelling on a passenger's lap.

However, the [Vickers Viking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickers_VC.1_Viking) was generally equipped with seatbelts. This undated picture of a Viking interior from the [SDASM](https://sandiegoairandspace.org/collection/image-collection) archives shows a buckled belt on the nearest seat.

[image: Vickers Viking - interior]
[source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/sdasmarchives/)

The Viking first flew in 1945. This picture from 1946 shows a Viking seat being manufactured, clearly with a seatbelt, indicating they probably were fitted from the outset.

[image: Vickers Viking - seat manufacture]

[source](https://www.mirrorpix.com/?17422710581083042885)